# how to reinstall pure-ftpd on debian?

Tags: debian, ftp

because i had problems with my pure-ftpd i decided to completely remove and reinstall it.

so i did like

```
apt-get remove pure-ftpd-mysql 
find / -name "pure-ftpd" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

now after reinstalling the init.d script and other pieces are still missing, i wonder how they got there initially...

Comment: You really shouldn't manually go through and delete things when you're using a package manager i.e. your `find / -name` line. Let the package manager do what it does and manage the files.

Comment: well, i didn't know about apt-get purge ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When use want a complete removing of a package you need
to purge it (usaualy it means removing also config files).

```
aptitude purge pure-ftpd-mysql
```

Anyway, when a config file for an installed package is missing, you can
use the following command to force dpkg to reinstall original missing
configuration files :

```
dpkg --force-confmiss -i /var/cache/apt/archives/pure-ftpd-mysql_1.0.24-1_i386.deb
```

Assuming you don't have done an:

```
apt-get clean
```

that remove the cache :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to purge it:

```
apt-get --purge remove pure-ftpd-mysql
apt-get --purge remove pure-ftpd
```